# Mesh moves to origin on animation

Tags: animation

So basically I am using Mixamo for animating characters (First time using it) and when I try to put 2 animations onto one mesh, It seems that once the first animation is over (which is a walking animation) the second one (which is a falling animation) refers back to the origin which is where the mesh was before it started walking, meaning that the mesh teleports back to the origin before it falls. I would supply a blend file but I'm not sure how.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

[image: Character at end of walking animation][Character when the falling animation starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbU62.jpg)

Comment: I guess the walk is not a walk cycle, in the sense that he moves away from its origin, so you can either: in Object mode, when the second animation begins, move the armature where it is supposed to be, or change the walk for a walk cycle and make the armature follow a curve.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a simmilar problem. While by all means I'm not a Blender pro, in my case the problem was simply solved by [applying the transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply).

Have you tried it?

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply but unfortunately it did not work. Thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the walk is not a walk cycle, in the sense that the bones move away from the armature's origin, he's not walking still like on a treadmill.

To make it clear, let say that you have a bone that have an action 1 which is a displacement away from the armature's origin (X0 to X+n). At frame 1 the bone will be at the armature's origin point, at frame 20 it will several units away.

Now there's action 2 (whatever it is) that also begin at the armature's origin point.

When you'll transition from action 1 and action 2, you'll see the bones jump back to the armature's origin. Blender has no reason to make the bones in action begin where they end in action 1. Only their local position (the relative to the origin) count.

[image]

So you have several solutions:

- Make a walk cycle, meaning a still walk as if your character was moving on a treadmill. You'll use a *Follow Path* constraint to make him move on the *Global* space. The advantage is that it won't jump at the beginning of the next action as your bones have not move away from the armature's origin. It maybe useful to have the walk cycle but maybe a bit time consuming if you just want to fix your current problem.
- In *Pose* mode make the second action begin where the first ends. Maybe the simplest way to fix your current problem.
- Keep the actions as they are but in *Object* mode select the armature, move it and create some keyframes to compensate the jump effect. Not very convenient trick though...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and help me. I am very new to animation in blender and when I make the second action begin where the first ends, It just goes back to the origin on frame 2. same with moving the armature in object mode. I'm sure I've probably done something wrong I'm just not sure what... I moved the armature on the first frame of action 2, to be a copy of the last frame of action one, but on the second frame it justs goes back to origin. Thank you

Comment: maybe share your armature only, use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/